# Put a dummy Facebook Login Button on my HTML/CSS code

Tags: html, css, facebook, button, authentication

I am a HTML/CSS coder and I need to put a Facebook login button in the HTMl/CSS code. I know that in order to have it working I need to register my site, get APP_ID, nut my responsibility is to have that button figured on the page that's it? How can it be done?

Comment: Have you checked out the [facebook login docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for just the button, that should be easy to do. According to the docs, you add the following to the page:

Just below the `<body>` tag add the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

*The wire-up will involve changing the `APP_ID` parameter to match the established app key*

Then, where ever you need the button, you can add:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-show-faces="false" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1"></div>
```

For more information/guidance, facebook has a [page on the login button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/).

Comment: Yes, but I have done that and it does not show the blue button.

Comment: @Karine: Chances are you need a valid app key for it to show up. (I believe the app key needs to have a domain associated with it that matches the domain the button's being viewed on).

Comment: @BradChristie you are correct, the button will only render if it's being called from the domain registered to the app_id